# Sending JSON in ActionScript 2

Tags: actionscript

anyone know how to send JSON in ActionScript 2?

I tried using XML() but it changes all " into " before sending it. Ex:

```
var callout = new XML({ "name": "John"})
callout.sendAndLoad('http://api.app.com', new XML());
```

but what gets sent is { "name": "John"}

also cannot upgrade to AS3 (wish i could)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976394/send-json-from-flash-to-php

That should do it

Comment: thanks but URLRequest is AS3 and not availabe in AS2

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it

Create a new class that extends LoadVars and override the "toString" method to return the JSON. You can then use load() and sendAndLoad() to send JSON to an URL

Example:

```
class SendJson extends LoadVars {

   public var data:String;  // Put your JSON here

   public function toString() {
      return data;
   }

}
```